# How can i toggle google maps markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way of quickly show/hide of google maps markers?

I don't want to remove/re-add every time, because I basically need to display them only on mouseover and hide on mouseout.

I tried with

```
marker.hide()
```

But I kinda get an ugly error because it seems that `hide` is available on gmaps2 but not on gmaps3 api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
marker.setVisible(false)
```

do what you need?